# How to decrypt(offline) value that is protected by SQL Server AEAD_AES_256_CBC_HMAC_SHA_256

Tags: sql-server, encryption-symmetric, data-protection, always-encrypted, azure-sql-server

It is possible to manually decrypt value that is encrypted by sql server always encrypted mechanizm? I mean how to decrypt column value that is encrypted by `AEAD_AES_256_CBC_HMAC_SHA_256` algorithm.

I have encryption key(in other topic I was asking about generating one) so i my opinion it should be possible.

I wanna be resistant to azure availability, so offline decryption is important feature for me.